# Why my code can't pass the test case from LeetCode 322 Coin Change?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/
My code can't pass some test cases from LeetCode:

```
def coinChange(coins, amount):
    """
    :type coins: List[int]
    :type amount: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    coins.sort()
    #init the dp list
    dp = [0]+[float('inf')]*amount
    for i in coins:
        for j in range(i,amount+1):
            dp[j] = min(dp[j],int(j/i)+dp[j%i])

    if dp[-1]==float('inf'):
        return -1
    else:
        return dp[-1]


#test cases1,the result should be 3    
coins = [1, 2, 5]
amount = 11
print(coinChange(coins,amount))
#test cases2,the result should be 20  
coins = [186,419,83,408]
amount = 6249
print(coinChange(coins,amount))
```

it should return 20 for the second test case but now it's -1.
I don't know why my code works on the first test case but not the second one.
Thanks

Comment: Your algorithm does not work for [2,5] and 11 = (2+2+2+5). I would expect some kind of recursion is needed, but my intuition might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I've got the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do in `dp[j] = min(dp[j],int(j/i)+dp[j%i])` but it should be `dp[j] = min(dp[j],1+dp[j-i])`. The reason being you can add this coin with amount `j-i` to get amount `j` with one more coin (this coin).